# How to merge a working branch and main branch in Git?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-branch

I have been working on a project and I'm using Git and Github for my version control.

I have a `main` branch  and a `product-page` branch. While I was working on `product-page`, I had to change something in main branch, so I made another branch `nav-change` from the `main` branch (and not the `product-page`) and I made a few changes and pushed it to Github and even merged it there and now the changes are part of my main branch, but now I want those changes to also be in `product-page` branch.

What should I do?

Comment: [cherry-picking](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) might be what you want.

Comment: Does nav-change still exist? If so just merge it into product-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `git merge` the `main` branch (with the additional changes from `nav-change`) in the branch `product-page`, where you need this additional changes.

But be careful, *merge conflicts* can arise!